# How to access object from another form c#

Tags: c#

So I have this class called Employee that stores the employee's username and password.

```
 class Employee
{
    string username;
    string password;

    public string Username
    {
        get { return username; }
        set { username = value; }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set { password = value; }
    }

    public Employee(string username, string password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

In my main class, I created an instance of Employee with some sample data.

```
Employee employee1 = new Employee("John", "123");
```

I included this piece of code in the main method to authenticate the user based on his/her username and password.

```
 do
        {
            Console.Write("Username: ");
            username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Password: ");
            password = Console.ReadLine();

            if (employee1.Username != username || employee1.Password != password)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Username or Password. Please Try again \n");
            }
        }
        while (employee1.Username != username || employee1.Password != password);

        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write("Login Sucessful!. Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Instead of having this chunk of code in my main class, I want to transfer this code in Employee.cs that acts as a method, and can be called from the main class. My problem is, how can I access the object from the main class, and get the initialized username and password to apply the same concept on Employee.cs.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like:

```
class Employee
{
     // Existing code above this

     public bool Authenticate() 
     {
         var authed = false;
         do
         {
             Console.Write("Username: ");
             var attemptUsername = Console.ReadLine();
             Console.Write("Password: ");
             var attemptPassword = Console.ReadLine();

             if (username != attemptUsername || password != attemptPassword)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Username or Password. Please Try again \n");
             }
             else 
             {
                 authed = true;
             }
         }
         while (!authed);

         Console.Clear();
         Console.Write("Login Sucessful!. Press any key to continue...");
         Console.ReadKey();

         return authed;
     }
}
```

Then you can go:

```
var john = new Employee("John", 123);
john.Authenticate(); // Waits until he enters valid password (Might want to add a max attempts to the Authenticate function and actually use the return value
```

NOTE: Depending on what framework etc you are using, it's normally a good idea to keep your `Employee / Veternerian` classes as POCO's and use services to add logic based around them.

Answer (score 2):

Is this you looking for ?

```
 class Mainclass
    {
        Main()
        {
           Employee employee1 = new Employee("John", "123");
           employee1.yourMethod();
        }

    }   


   public class Employee
        {
            string username;
            string password;
        .
        .
        .
        public void yourMethod()
        {
               do
                {
                    Console.Write("Username: ");
                    username = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Password: ");
                    password = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (veterinarian1.Username != username || veterinarian1.Password != password)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Username or Password. Please Try again \n");
                    }
                }
                while (veterinarian1.Username != username || veterinarian1.Password != password);

                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write("Login Sucessful!. Press any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey();
        }

        }
```

Comment: Yes, but I can't reach employee1 from that method in Employee.cs.

Comment: Ok just add public before your Employee declaration 'public class Employee'

Comment: Nope I still can access the employee1 obbject from the Employee class :/

Comment: You want to access employee1 object in Mainclass from Employee class ?

Comment: Yes so I can get it's username and password which I initialized in the instance in the main class

Comment: That username and password is accessible (you can get) by using this.username and this.password in yourMethod()